# Finding repeating patterns between strings

Tags: r, regex

I have different user inputted vectors of strings identifying files, and they might come in unpredictable formats:

```
prec_names <- 
c("prec_01", "prec_02", "prec_03", "prec_04", "prec_05", "prec_06")

tmean_names <- 
c("tmean1", "tmean2", "tmean3", "tmean4", "tmean5", "tmean6")

tmin_names <- 
c("1tmin", "2tmin", "3tmin", "4tmin", "5tmin", "6tmin")
```

Is there any function that identifies the repeating sequences of characters in each vector, regardless of length and position?

The result I want is:

```
FUN(prec_names)
> "prec_0"

FUN(tmean_names)
> "tmean"

FUN(tmin_names)
> "tmin"
```

Comment: In your example, why the repeating sequence is not `prec_0`?

Comment: Your repeating sequence have always numbers or there are also other character that you want to remove?

Comment: Yes, it should be ```prec_0```, I'm going to edit it. It is not necessarily numbers, it could be month names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about your exact goal, but the following code can help you find the intersected segments among similar strings:

```
library(vecsets)
f <- function(s) intToUtf8(Reduce(vintersect,lapply(s, utf8ToInt)))
```

such that

```
> f(prec_names)
[1] "prec_0"

> f(tmean_names)
[1] "tmean"

> f(tmin_names)
[1] "tmin"
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed. My goal is to fix a bug people were having while using a function that I wrote. The function just loads and organizes climatic layers in a way they can be used in another function to easily do operations in them. Users were coming up with layers from other databases I hadn't considered and they had all kinds of names, so I was trying to standardize layer names as they are loaded, as the names are important for identifying which variable and month the climatic layers refer to.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to remove the numbers with `sub` and apply `unique` on it

```
f1 <- function(vec) unique(sub("\\d+", "", vec))
```

-testing

```
f1(prec_names)
#[1] "prec_"
f1(tmean_names)
#[1] "tmean"
f1(tmin_names)
#[1] "tmin"
```

If there are multiple instances, use `gsub` instead of `sub`